# Given no modulus or if even/odd function, how would one check for an odd or even number?

Tags: testing, math

I have recently sat a computing exam in university in which we were never taught beforehand about the modulus function or any other check for odd/even function and we have no access to external documentation except our previous lecture notes. Is it possible to do this without these and how?

Comment: My naive approach would be: divide by 2 and check if the result has digits after the comma not equal to 0 => odd, if the result has digits after the comma equal to 0 => even.

Comment: Was not using these functions a hard requirement, or are you assuming that you could only use content from the slides? In my student times, it was not rare for professors to about knowledge outside the explicit curriculum, particularly for such a basic operation as the modulus. In any case there are several ways, as its already been shown by now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out from a fellow student how to solve this simplistically with maths instead of functions.

Using (-1)^n   :

If n is odd then the outcome is -1

If n is even then the outcome is 1

This is some pretty out-of-the-box thinking, but it would be the only way to solve this without previous knowledge of complex functions including mod.

Answer (score 1):

**Bitwise AND (&)**

Extract the last bit of the number using the bitwise AND operator. If the last bit is 1, then it's odd, else it's even. This is the simplest and most efficient way of testing it. Examples in some languages:

**C / C++ / C#**

```
bool is_even(int value) {
    return (value & 1) == 0;
}
```

**Java**

```
public static boolean is_even(int value) {
    return (value & 1) == 0;
}
```

**Python**

```
def is_even(value):
    return (value & 1) == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is only for `integer` numbers as the concept of odd/even eludes me for floating point values.

For these `integer` numbers, the check of the Least Significant Bit (LSB) as proposed by [Rotem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58642917/3460361) is the most straightforward method, but there are **many** other ways to accomplish that.

For example, you could use the *integer division* operation as a test. This is one of the most basic operation which is implemented in virtually every platform. The result of an integer division is always another `integer`. For example:

```
>> x = int64( 13 ) ;
>> x / 2
ans =
                    7
```

Here I cast the value `13` as a `int64` to make sure MATLAB treats the number as an `integer` instead of `double` data type.
Also here the result is actually rounded towards infinity to the next integral value. This is MATLAB specific implementation, other platform might round down but it does not matter for us as the only behavior we look for is the rounding, whichever way it goes. The rounding allow us to define the following behavior:

- If a number is **even**: Dividing it by 2 will produce an exact result, such that if we multiply this result by 2, we obtain the original number.
- If a number is **odd**: Dividing it by 2 will result in a rounded result, such that multiplying it by 2 will yield a different number than the original input.

Now you have the logic worked out, the code is pretty straightforward:

```
%% sample input
x = int64(42) ;
y = int64(43) ;

%% define the checking function
%   uses only multiplication and division operator, no high level function
is_even = @(x) int64(x) == (int64(x)/2)*2 ;
```

And obvisouly, this will yield:

```
>> is_even(x)
ans =
     1
>> is_even(y)
ans =
     0
```

Comment: I like your thinking, but I was not aware of how to convert to integer. I give this answer a solid 8.5/10 -> 9/10 cause integers :)